# Enable code completion to a database in PyCharm for a .py file

Tags: pycharm

how can I enable code completion to a database in PyCharm for a `.py` file?
For example, when I type `c.execute('SELECT* FROM pub\<cursor position>')` and I have a publication table in a database, I want PyCharm to suggest publication as an option to complete `pub` .

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you use PyCharm Professional or Community?

Comment: Professional. And sorry for the late answer.